# Python: pip install wheel dependencies from a folder

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I know that I can create a wheel by first writing a `setup.py` and then typing

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

If my wheels depend only on packages in pypi I know that I can install them by doing:

```
pip install mypkg.whl
```

Question: if my wheels depend on other of my wheels, can I have pip automatically install them from a folder? Essentially using a folder as a poor man's private pypi

To be more specific, if in `pkg1` I have a `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    name = "pkg1",
    install_requires = ["requests"],
    ...
)
```

And in `pkg2` I have:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    name = "pkg2",
    install_requires = ["pkg1"],
    ...
)
```

This will fail on installation because pip will try to look for `pkg1` in pypi. Is it possible to tell it to just look in a folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
pip install --find-links /path/to/wheel/dir/ pkg2
```

If you want to completely disable access to PyPI add `--no-index`:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/wheel/dir/ pkg2
```

Comment: Ok but how do you find the wheel directory programmatically?

Comment: @cowlinator Why would you want to do that? Sorry, cannot resist. ;-) The OP already has the wheel in a directory. If you want to download wheels use `pip download`. If you have another question please ask it separately; comments are for discussion of existing question and answers.

Comment: On Windows, Python 3.6.8 I had to remove the `--find-links` option in order for it to work.